# Invalid content was found starting with element 'sport'. One of '{spalanie}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been trying to solve this issue, but I can't understand where it comes from:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'sport'. One of '{spalanie}' is expected.

Here's part of the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<spinning>
  <tabela>
    <porownanie waga="45">
      <sport>Bieg 11km/h</sport>
      <spalanie>610</spalanie>
      <sport>Skakana</sport>
      <spalanie>500</spalanie>
      <sport>Pływanie 50m/min</sport>
      <spalanie>325</spalanie>
      <sport>Spinning</sport>
      <spalanie>800</spalanie>    
     </porownanie>
 </tabela>
```

Here's the following XSD:

```
<xsd:schema version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


  <xsd:element name="spinning" type="spinning_typ"/>

<xsd:complexType name="spinning_typ">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="tabela" type="tabela_typ" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element name="zapisy" type="zapisy_typ"/>
      <xsd:element name="sprzet" type="sprzet_typ"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:complexType name="tabela_typ">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="porownanie" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="sport"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="spalanie" type="xsd:decimal"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:attribute ref="waga"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Xml sample represents the desired schema, your xsd for the sequence inside `porownanie` should look like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="tabela_typ">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="porownanie" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" name="sport"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" name="spalanie" type="xsd:decimal"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
       <xsd:attribute ref="waga"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

You have a repeating sequence of exactly 2 elements `sport` and `spalanie`.